# The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'DAILY_REPORT'. A member of the type, 'REPORT_ID', does not have a corresponding column

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to select data from SQL SERVER using stored procedure and ASP.NET MVC  but when click FIND button I got this error :

```
Additional information: The data reader is incompatible with the specified Model.DAILY_REPORT'. A member of the type, 'REPORT_ID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

This is stored procedure :

```
create  proc [dbo].[FIND_DAILY_REPORT1]
@start datetime,
@end   datetime
As
begin
SELECT hospital_name , day_name  , report_date  , report_time ,  lab_manager , sys_users.user_name 
from daily_report
inner join sys_users on daily_report.user_id = sys_users.user_id 
and report_date between @start and @end
end
```

this is the context class and the error show in return :

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<DAILY_REPORT> FindDailyReports(Nullable<System.DateTime> start, Nullable<System.DateTime> end)
        {
            var startParameter = start.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("start", start) :
                new ObjectParameter("start", typeof(System.DateTime));
    
            var endParameter = end.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("end", end) :
                new ObjectParameter("end", typeof(System.DateTime));
    
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<DAILY_REPORT>("FindDailyReports", startParameter, endParameter);
        }
```

This is controller markup :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var dAILY_REPORT = db.DAILY_REPORT;
            return View(dAILY_REPORT.ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Index(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            return View(db.FindDailyReports(start, end));
        }
```

this is the view :

```
@model IEnumerable<warehouse.Models.DAILY_REPORT>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";
}

<h2 style="direction:rtl;margin-left:600px;">التقرير اليومي لكل المستشفيات</h2>



    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DAILY_REPORT", FormMethod.Post))
    {
       <span>From Date:</span> <input type="date" name="start"/>
       <span>To Date:</span> <input type="date" name="end"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Find Reports"/>


<table class="table table-bordered" style="direction:rtl;text-align:right">
    <tr>
        <th>اسم المستشفى   </th>
        <th> اليوم  </th>
        <th> تاريخ التقرير   </th>
        <th> وقت التقرير    </th>
        <th> مدير المختبر  </th>
      

    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.hospital_name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DAY_NAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.REPORT_DATE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.REPORT_TIME)
        </td>
       
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LAB_MANAGER)
        </td>
       
      
        <td>
            
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.REPORT_ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.REPORT_ID })
            
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
    }
```

I don't need to use the column report id only want to filter and search data between two dates

How to solve this error please ?